# How to make div below another div

Tags: css, html, margin

I want the `#blue` div below the `#green` div

The `#blue` div has `margin-top : -10px; attribute`

```
 <style>
    #red{
        width: 400px;

        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    #green{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: green;
        border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #blue{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-top: 2px solid brown;
        margin-top: -10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    </style>


<div id="red">
    <div id="green">
    </div>
    <div id="blue">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you Googled it? There's about 50 duplicate questions. Also, your code **already works**.

Comment: What is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/am9zS/

Comment: I'd guess that adding `position: relative;` to both the green and blue `div` elements would allow the `z-index` to kick in, but I don't know if it'd work well in all browsers (I'm thinking of earlier versions of IE here...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably adding `position:absolute` on the `#blue` and `#green` div and `position:relative` on the `#red` div would do what you want, as I suspect you need one to be behind another. If they need to be one after another then use relative positioning on blue and green too.

Comment: check also this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eGpUM/ , where I added it to your above code.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see the problem, your code is fine. Or did you mean under div? Like the blue div hidden under the green div? Well then you need to add the position: relative ( or absoulte ) attribute on the div you want to move/hide. nad then top or left. Example:

```
        #blue{
    /* without position: relative/absoulte the z-index wont work!*/
        position:relative;
/* this moves the dives up or down*/
        top: -100px;
/* this move the div left or right! */
left: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-top: 2px solid brown;
        margin-top: -10px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```